# Unmet dependencies on Debian

Tags: apache, dependencies, debian, stretch

I have unmet dependencies for libapache2-mod-php7.0. In my attempt to fix this issue I have been playing around with my sources and have done a variety of upgrades. I was on Stretch when I started, I know I've probably gone about it the wrong way but I like to try before I ask.

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux stable-updates (sid)
Release:        stable-updates
Codename:       sid
```

cat /etc/issue.net

```
Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
```

cat /proc/version

```
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.93-1
```

apt-get update
apt-get updgrade

```
...
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                     Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

apt --fix-broken install

```
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.29-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp', which is also in package apache2.2-bin 2.2.22-13+deb7u12
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.29-1_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get -f install

```
...
Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.25-3+deb9u3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.25-3+deb9u3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp', which is also in package apache2.2-bin 2.2.22-13+deb7u12
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.25-3+deb9u3_amd64.deb
W: http: aptMethod::Configuration: could not load seccomp policy: Invalid argument
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

dpkg --configure -a

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.0:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on apache2-api-20120211; however:    
  Package apache2-api-20120211 is not installed.    
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16); however:
  Package apache2-bin is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.14.0-1-amd64 (4.14.2-1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.14.0-1-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/dev/disk/by-uuid/1cd988f1-4ed7-4bb1-81a5-15f7dc900a47'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.14.0-1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.14.0-1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-4.14.0-1-amd64; however:
  Package linux-image-4.14.0-1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0:
 php7.0 depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0 | php7.0-fpm | php7.0-cgi; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.
  Package php7.0-fpm is not installed.
  Package php7.0-cgi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php:
 php depends on php7.0; however:
  Package php7.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of phpmyadmin:
 phpmyadmin depends on php; however:
  Package php is not configured yet.
  Package php7.0 which provides php is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 linux-image-4.14.0-1-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
 php7.0
 php
 phpmyadmin
```

apt-get -u dist-upgrade

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                     Depends: apache2-bin (>= 2.4.16) but it is not installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What else can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove apache

```
apt-get remove apache2.2-bin
```

you can force the installation of apache2-bin:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.20-2_amd64.deb
```

and then try

```
apt-get -f install
```

for me it worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps

```
1. sudo apt-get update 
2. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
3. apt-get install -f --reinstall apache2
```

-f to fix unmet dependencies.